# how to add a clip toggle effect to a static bit of jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle, side-effects

I'm pretty new to jquery and I've been trying to add a 'clip' slide-open effect to a static bit of jquery I have.

this is the effect that I'm after...

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=jquery_142

and this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
  div { margin: 0px; width: 100%; height: 80px; background: green; position: relative; }
</style>

  <script>
var divs = $('section div'),
    links = $('a');

links.click(function(){
    $(this.hash).toggle().siblings().hide();
});

  </script>

  <style>

  section div { 
    display: none;
    width:100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lime;
}

nav a {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>

</head>
<body style="margin:0px;">

<section>
    <div id="1">
        <a href="#1" style="float:right;">X</a>
        <a href="#2">next &raquo;</a>
    </div>

    <div id="2">
        <a href="#2" style="float:right;">X</a>
        <a href="#1">&laquo; prev</a>
        <a href="#3">next &raquo;</a>
    </div>

    <div id="3">
        <a href="#3" style="float:right;">X</a>
        <a href="#2">&laquo; prev</a>
        <a href="#4">next &raquo;</a>
    </div>

    <div id="4">
        <a href="#4" style="float:right;">X</a>
        <a href="#3">&laquo; prev</a>
        <a href="#1">next &raquo;</a>
    </div>
</section>

<nav>
<a href="#1">one</a>
<a href="#2">two</a>
<a href="#3">three</a>
<a href="#4">four</a>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

you can see it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/greggb/8gfEZ/1/

Any help with this would be great, I've tried loads of forums but just cant get my head round how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after something like the [jQuery UI slide](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide) effect